# Django Registration - Need a simple way to default username to a randomly generated string

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm using Django Registration. It provides the view that processes registration_form.html that currently contains Username, Password1, Password2 and Email as user-enterable fields in my app. I have a very simple random username generator that I would like to use to pre-populate username in registration_form.html and make it "readonly". I'm having a hard time figuring out where in Django Registration I should make my tweaks. I believe it's in here somewhere:

```
class RegistrationView(_RequestPassingFormView):
"""
Base class for user registration views.

"""
disallowed_url = 'registration_disallowed'
form_class = RegistrationForm
http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head', 'options', 'trace']
success_url = None
template_name = 'registration/registration_form.html'

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Check that user signup is allowed before even bothering to
    dispatch or do other processing.

    """
    if not self.registration_allowed(request):
        return redirect(self.disallowed_url)
    return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def form_valid(self, request, form):
    new_user = self.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
    success_url = self.get_success_url(request, new_user)

    # success_url may be a simple string, or a tuple providing the
    # full argument set for redirect(). Attempting to unpack it
    # tells us which one it is.
    try:
        to, args, kwargs = success_url
        return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
    except ValueError:
        return redirect(success_url)

def registration_allowed(self, request):
    """
    Override this to enable/disable user registration, either
    globally or on a per-request basis.

    """
    return True

def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):
    """
    Implement user-registration logic here. Access to both the
    request and the full cleaned_data of the registration form is
    available here.

    """
    raise NotImplementedError
```

UPDATE:

So based on initial responses I started with a quick edit of the existing RegistrationView as follows:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
required_css_class = 'required'

# username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
#                             max_length=30,
#                             label=_("Username"),
#                             error_messages={'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})   
# My new username stuff here:                     
n = random.randint(1,9999999)
default_username = 'AnonMom%d' % (n,) 
username = forms.CharField(initial="default_username") 
email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"))
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            label=_("Password"))
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            label=_("Password (again)"))
```

I was expecting to see my default username show up in registration.form.html defined as follows:

```
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}

<p><input id="id_username" maxlength="25" name="username" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>
<p style="font-size:12px; color:#999">Make it anonymous but easy to remember. 25 chars max. No spaces.</p>  
<p><input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password" placeholder="Password"/></p>
<p><input id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password" placeholder="Password (Confirm)"/></p>
<p><input id="id_email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email (Never displayed)" autocomplete="off"/></p>
```

But the field is empty. It's even empty if I just set initial="xxx". What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE 2:

It's all working using the code above with the following slight teak to the view and form:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):                           
    n = random.randint(1,9999999)
    username = forms.CharField(initial='MomzAnon%d' % (n,) ) 
    ...

<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    <p><input id="id_username" maxlength="25" name="username" type="text" 
    value="{{ form.username.value }}" readonly autocomplete="off"></p>
    ...
```

Final question: Is there any reason to subclass RegistrationForm vs just edit it? My approach seems very simple in terms of lines of code.

UPDATE 3:
It seems that my random username is not being auto-generated each time I call this form. So I'm coming back to this form having created one user and finding that the auto-generated username is unchanged from the last user registration. How can I force a username regen each time this form is presented to users?

UPDATE 4:
I solved the problem outlined in UPDATE 3 by moving the username logic here. This code also includes a tweak to ensure my randomly generated username is also unique:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    n = random.randint(1,999999) 
    new_username = 'anon%d' % (n,) 

    while User.objects.filter(username=new_username).exists():
        n = random.randint(1,999999)
        new_username = 'anon%d' % (n,) 

    self.fields['username'] = forms.CharField(initial=new_username)
```

Comment: I think you would need to create a new form (without `username`) and then create the random `username` in a custom view that subclasses `RegistrationView` ideally after all the other fields in the form have been validated.

Comment: Now that I look at it, You might be able to make it happen by just subclassing `RegistrationView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass `RegistrationForm` and make username field as readonly by adding `readonly` widget attribute :

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class MyForm(RegistrationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label=_("Username"),
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
```

In your `RegistrationView` subclass change `form_class` to your form class and override `get_initial` function (your generation random password code can be placed here to):

```
class MyReg(RegistrationView):
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_initial(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.initial = {'username': self.gen_randrom_username()}
        return super(Myreg, self).get_initial(*args, **kwargs)

    def gen_randrom_username(self):
        # gen name
        return random_username
```

Comment: Thanks. See my UPDATE above. I tried a simple first step of editing the existing RegistrationView without success.

Comment: @user2916527 if you will subclass RegistrationForm you can more easily update django-registration package...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `RegistrationView`

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite, Site
from registration import signals
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView

class RandomRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):
        email, password = cleaned_data['email'], cleaned_data['password1']
        username = call_random_username_genator() # <- supply your RANDOM username here

        if Site._meta.installed:
            site = Site.objects.get_current()
        else:
            site = RequestSite(request)                         
        new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
                                                                    password, site)
        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                     user=new_user,
                                     request=request)
        return new_user
```

And in your `urls.py` add something like

```
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', RandomRegistrationView.as_view(),
        name='registration_register'),
```

This isn't tested but it should get you close. I think you might need to create a new `RegistrationForm` and supply it in `urls.py` with

```
RandomRegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RandomRegistrationForm)
```

Or you may simply be able to make the necessary changes in the template. I'm not 100% sure without actually implementing it.

Comment: Keep in mind that `django-registration` does not come with templates. Whatever `registration_form.html` is implemented as it will be given the `RegistrationForm` context containing specific input fields (`username`, `email`, `password1`, `password2` in this case). You can either loop over all of the fields in the template or implement them (or not implement) individually.

Comment: You could easily provide your own form class as well as an alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414926/how-to-use-different-form-in-django-registration

Comment: I took a simple first step inspired by your input and couldn't get an edited version of the original RegistrationView to pass an initial value for username. See my UPDATE above.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass RegistrationForm to set initial value and readonly attribute, like this:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['username'] = random_username()
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'readonly': 'readonly'})
```

and of course set the above form class as your registration form.